# Draw polyline using google map in iOS 7?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, google-maps, ios7

Using this [link](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=coordinatesFrom&destination=coordinatesTo&sensor=false) .

i tried to get route direction from one coordinates to another coordinates but didn't get route. Below mention used coding...

```
        NSArray *routesArray = [res objectForKey:@"routes"]; 
        NSDictionary *routeDict = [routesArray objectAtIndex:0];
        NSDictionary *routeOverviewPolyline = [routeDict objectForKey:@"overview_polyline"];
        NSString *points = [routeOverviewPolyline objectForKey:@"points"];
        GMSPath *path = [GMSPath pathFromEncodedPath:points];

        polyline = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];
        polyline.strokeColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        polyline.strokeWidth = 10.f;

        polyline.map = mapView_;
```

Can anyone know.Help me to solve this issue..

Answer (score 10):

You can use [GoogleMapsDirection](https://github.com/Djengo/GoogleMapsDirection) to get the path or DirectionResponse from the [Google Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#DirectionsResponses). The NSLogs are useful to see what you are working with.

```
[[GMDirectionService sharedInstance] getDirectionsFrom:origin to:destination        succeeded:^(GMDirection *directionResponse) {   
    if ([directionResponse statusOK]){
        NSLog(@"Duration : %@", [directionResponse durationHumanized]);
        NSLog(@"Distance : %@", [directionResponse distanceHumanized]);
        NSArray *routes = [[directionResponse directionResponse] objectForKey:@"routes"];
        // NSLog(@"Route : %@", [[directionResponse directionResponse] objectForKey:@"routes"]);

    }
} failed:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Can't reach the server")
}];
```

Once you have the json you can get the path points (this shows the first route at index 0).

```
GMSPath *path = [GMSPath pathFromEncodedPath:routes[0][@"overview_polyline"][@"points"]];
```

Then you can convert the path to a polyline and draw it on your mapView and set the strokeColor and strokeWidth if desired.

```
GMSPolyline *polyline = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];
polyline.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
polyline.strokeWidth = 5.f;
```

Then set the polyline.map property to your mapView.

```
polyline.map = mapView;
```

Finally put it all together

```
[[GMDirectionService sharedInstance] getDirectionsFrom:origin to:destination          succeeded:^(GMDirection *directionResponse) {   
    if ([directionResponse statusOK]){
        NSLog(@"Duration : %@", [directionResponse durationHumanized]);
        NSLog(@"Distance : %@", [directionResponse distanceHumanized]);
        NSArray *routes = [[directionResponse directionResponse] objectForKey:@"routes"];
        // NSLog(@"Route : %@", [[directionResponse directionResponse] objectForKey:@"routes"]);

        GMSPath *path = [GMSPath pathFromEncodedPath:routes[0][@"overview_polyline"]  [@"points"]];
        GMSPolyline *polyline = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];
        polyline.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
        polyline.strokeWidth = 5.f;
        polyline.map = mapView;

    }
} failed:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Can't reach the server")
}];
```

I find [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org/) useful for installing the Google Maps SDK and GoogleMapsDirection.

Comment: hi... its always failed the request .can you please tell me what should be the result.. i have used your code to get direction and polyline

Comment: It requires "AFNetworking", and Current Version for AFNetworking is 2.3.1 and its not have AFHttpClient Class which require for "GMHTTPClient" as a base class.
if we use older version of "AFNetworking" then its work fine